# Taking values from table and presenting it in a specific arrangement

Tags: excel, vba

I would like your help as I am completely new to coding in VBA.

I am creating an excel sheet where the user in puts some values (a, b, c, d etc) and the excel presents them in the following format.

```
"Units","a"
"Section","b"
"Part","c"
"Lives","d"
"Loade1"
"Smax","f1"
"Smin","g1"
"Kt","h1"
```

In the above format, I have an excel table where e1,f1, g1 and h1 will be entered in the table rows.

Therefore, I need the lines starting from Load to be repeated as many times as there are rows in the table, with the values being taken from the row being referred (i.e. Row 2 means e2, f2 g2 etc)

I tried the following partial code to atleast see wether the macro was recording the proper format:

```
Sub Copy_Main()
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Load_num As Integer
Dim Smax As Integer
Dim Smin As Integer
Dim Kt As Integer
Dim Repeats As Integer
Dim Lives As Variant
Dim Pair As String
Lives = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8").Value2
Count = 1
Load_num = Count
Smax = [Stress_Table[Smax]].Rows(Count)
Smin = [Stress_Table[Smin]].Rows(Count)
Kt = [Stress_Table[Kt]].Rows(Count)
Repeats = [Stress_Table[Repeats]].Rows(Count)
Pair = Chr(34) & "Load" & Load_num & Chr(34)
MsgBox (Pair)

End Sub
```

I tried to view the value of pair, but not able to get this initial code running at all.

Could anyone could point out the mistake in the code above? or If anyone could help me out with the main problem itself, that would be even better:P

Comment: What error are you getting and where?

Comment: I had used Set statement before the line Lives = ... But it throws a Object required error.